# Processing 2.0 array sort

Tags: arrays, sorting, processing

I am getting this error while trying to sort an array of objects:

*the method sort (byte[]) in the type PApplet is not applicable for the arguments (sketch_124453.Word[])*

To support sort, I saw that one has to implement Comparable, hence my class code below.

But its not working so I wonder if sorting object arrays is possible with Processing 2.0+? Is this solution approach that I have done specific only to Processing 1.0?

```
class Word implements Comparable  {
  String s;
  int n=0;
  Word(String theWord) {
    s = theWord;
    n = 1;
  }
  //if we want to sort based on the n value of Word object:
  int compareTo(Object o)
  {
    Word other=(Word)o;
    if(other.n>n)  return -1;
    if(other.n==n) return 0;
    return 1;
  }

  int compareTo(Word o)
  {    
    if(o.n>n)  return -1;
    if(o.n ==n) return 0;
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to use Comparable you need to use Java's `Arrays.sort()` instead of Processing's one. Also AFAIK you don't need two `compareTo()` functions. As a bonus I made a `toString` function so `println()` can handle the object properly.

check it out;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

Word[] words = new Word[3];

void setup() {

  words[0] = new Word("three", 3);
  words[1] = new Word("two", 2);
  words[2] = new Word("one", 1);

  println(words);

  Arrays.sort(words);

  println("sorted:");
  println(words);
}



class Word implements Comparable {
  String s;
  int n;
  Word(String theWord, int _n) {
    s = theWord;
    n = _n ;
  }
  //if we want to sort based on the n value of Word object:
  int compareTo(Object o)
  {
    Word other=(Word)o;
    if (other.n > n)  return -1;
    if (other.n == n) return 0;
    return 1;
  }

  String toString() {
    return s + " - n = " + n;
  }
}
```

As you need to import `java.util.Arrays` this won't work in processingjs.